# How to add a new VPN connection in Loki using .ovpn file?

Tags: release-loki, openvpn, vpn

In KDE I have a button "Import" which can be used to import VPN connection from `.ovpn` file.

How to do it in elementary OS Loki?

Comment: You will need to install OpenVPN support before you do anything else. In Freya this used to involve installing the `networkmanager-openvpn` package, however I'm not sure whether this step is required for Loki or if it comes preinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

In Loki, openvpn and networkmanager-openvpn are already installed.

To import an *.ovpn, you need to make sure you have certificate files separate from the *.ovpn.

Then go to System Settings -> Network -> VPN. Click the "+", then in the window that pops up, click on "Add".

In the dropdown you'll see "Import a Saved VPN connection".

Comment: OMG! Elementary team what you are doing? You think we must do this bull**** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6-43ucVh44 like this just to connect by openvpn? -_- crazy guys

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python script that will do the cert separation for you
https://gist.github.com/seebk/bb94a7fd70d4cc454aaa